# Groovy script to find build status of jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, groovy, jenkins

I am using groovy script to get the build status of a jenkins job running currently as a post build action, like this:

```
def result = manager.build.result  
manager.listener.logger.println "And the result is: ${result}"
```

Now I want to send the value of "result" variable to a specific location in a file
Since I am new to groovy, I don't know much, Is there a way to achieve this, like we do in shell scripts:

```
echo $result > file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just write a line once to the file you can use next call:

```
new File("file").write(result)
```