# Get BuildStatus from triggered Freestyle Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I use something like the following code to trigger multiple Freestyle Jobs inside my Jenkins Job

```
[...]
stage('build') {
    try{
        parallel(
            build1: {
                def buildJob1 = build job: build1, parameters:[string(name: 'CPNUM_PARAM', value: CPNUM_PARAM)]

                buildJob1BuildNum = buildJob1.getNumber().toString()
            },

            build2: {
                def buildJob2 = build job: build2, parameters[string(name: 'CPNUM_PARAM', value: CPNUM_PARAM)]

                buildJob1BuildNum = buildJob1.getNumber().toString()
            },
            failFast: false
        )
    } catch (e){
         [...]
    }
}
[...]
```

The line `buildJob#BuildNum = buildJob#.getNumber().toString()` allows me to retrieve the BuildNumber of the triggered job.

Now I am searching for a way to retrieve the Buildstatus (success/unstable/failed) But I cant find anything.
I tried:

`buildJob#BuildStatus = buildJob#.getStatus().toString()`
`buildJob#BuildStatus = buildJob#.getBuildStatus().toString()`

etc. but none of them are working. I also failed to find some informations on the web.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578715/groovy-script-to-find-build-status-of-jenkins

Comment: This would only be a compromise to get the status. The problem is that I have n different slaves which are executing the buildjobs. So I would have to copy each file to my master. Because of the possibility to get the Buildnumber with an easy `get` call I think that there must be a way to get the status..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
buildStatus = buildJob1.getResult().toString()
```

works fin for me